# How to align multiple TextViews and multiple EditTexts Vertically regardless of the string size font

Tags: android, android-edittext, textview

What I need to do is align vertically the EditText to the center, and align vertically to the left the TextEdit.

Example: 
Apple          _______
Orange         _______
Watermelon     _______

I already tried the functions below but it seems to not work because the font of size of each letter is different

Example:
I*_____
Q*_____

Where * is a space so EditText ____ is not aligned

```
//Right padding
    public static String padRight(String s, int n) {
         return String.format("%1$-" + n + "s", s);  
    }


    //Left padding
    public static String padLeft(String s, int n) {
        return String.format("%1$" + n + "s", s);  
    }



 <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textViewUserWeist"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"              
                android:gravity="left"
                android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"
                android:text="Apple"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textColor="@color/black" />
            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editWeist"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"                
                android:gravity="center|top"
                android:hint="..."
                android:background="@drawable/draw_rounded_edittext"
                android:textCursorDrawable="@drawable/draw_color_cursor" />

     </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textViewUserHips"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"               
                android:gravity="left"
                android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"
                android:text="Grape"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textColor="@color/black" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editHips"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"                
                android:gravity="center|top"
                android:hint="..."
                android:background="@drawable/draw_rounded_edittext"
                android:textCursorDrawable="@drawable/draw_color_cursor" />
           </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, as far as I understand what are you trying to accomplish, change the orientation of the first LinearLayout to "vertical" should do the trick. Anyway for a better performance you should use instead a RelativeLayout to reduce the layouts inflated inside the view.

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
...
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks for the tips I will look at it. @Jonathan Aste